# Customizing SwiftUI view when app is launched from a watchOS complication

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm working on my first watchOS app.  This is an independent SwiftUI app that only needs to work on watchOS 9.x and also includes a few different watch face complications.  When the app launches, I determine which view to show based on a certain condition.  To accomplish this, I have an observable object defined like this:

```
class PresentedView : ObservableObject {
    
    enum Views {
        case first
        case second
    }

    @Published var currentView: Views = .first
}
```

When the app launches, I determine which view to show, update the .currentView property on PresentedView and then show a root view with the presentedView instance added as an environment object like this:

```
@main
struct Watch_App: App {

    private var presentedView = PresentedView()
    
    init() {
       if some_condition == true {
           presentedView.currentView = .first
       } else {
           presentedView.currentView = .second
       }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            RootView()
                .environmentObject(presentedView)
        }
    }
}
```

My root view simply looks at the .currentView property on the presentedView environment object and then returns the appropriate view:

```
struct RootView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var presentedView: PresentedView
    
    var body: some View {
        switch presentedView.currentView {
        case .first:
            FirstView()
        case .second:
            SecondView()
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned previously, I've also built a few simple watch face complications for the app.  Obviously, tapping one of the complications will launch the app and I'd like to be able to tell which complication was tapped so that I can customize some things about the view that's displayed as well as the behavior of the app.

I see that it's possible to use `widgetURL(_:)` on a complication view to set a URL that can be handled by the app in `onOpenURL(perform:)`.  So I added `onOpenURL(perform:)` to RootView like this:

```
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        RootView()
            .environmentObject(presentedView)
            .onOpenURL { url in
                print("URL from complication: \(url.absoluteString)")
            }
    }
}
```

Now I'm able to tell which complication was tapped by using `widgetURL(_:)` to set a unique URL for each complication.  There are four complications so four possible URLs could be passed into the app when it launches (or no URL at all if the user starts the app directly using the app icon).

As for customizing the view that gets displayed (and the behavior of the app), I thought the easiest way to do this might be to add another environment object to RootView that could be accessed by both FirstView and SecondView.  Let's call it "AppCustomization".  But then I thought of a couple of potential issues with this approach:

1. Each time the app is launched, I (potentially) need to reset/set some properties on the AppCustomization object inside of `onOpenURL(perform:)` but then also add the object to the environment via a call to `environmentObject(_:)` on RootView.  And I'm not sure if `onOpenURL(perform:)` would always be called before `environmentObject(_:)`.
2. In addition to customizing the appearance of my view(s) based on how the app was launched, I also want to make some adjustments to the behavior of the app so my view models would also need to access the information in the AppCustomization object and I'm not sure how a view model is able to access an environment object (unless you inject it somehow?).

Now I'm thinking that maybe I could simply store this info in user defaults and that would be a simple way to make it accessible to both my views and view models.  SwiftUI and watchOS are both somewhat new to me so it's possible that I may just be ignorant of a better option to do this.  Does anyone have any other suggestions for how this could be achieved?  Thanks very much!

Comment: did u find any solution?